# PHP - Looking for better way to add specific key in front of items of nested array items

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested

In a lot of projects I give the nested array/objects an identifier as key or index with a helper-function like this:

```php
function foo($array, $key) {

    foreach($array AS $idx => $item) {
        $array[$item[$key]] = $item;
        unset($array[$idx]);
    }
    
    return $array;
}

$array = foo($array, 'id');
```

With a conversion like this, it is just easier to target the items in the array.

##### Examlple:

- `$array['A12314']`
- `$array['A12312']['status']`

#### Question

But isn't there already a better way to achieve that (maybe something build-in or just more handy)?

---

#### Source-Array

```php
[
    [
        "id"      => "A12312",
        "status"  => false,
        "enabled" => true,
    ],
    [
        "id"      => "A12313",
        "status"  => false,
        "enabled" => false,
    ],
    [
        "id"      => "A12314",
        "status"  => true,
        "enabled" => false,
    ],
    [
        "id"      => "A12315",
        "status"  => true,
        "enabled" => true,
    ],
]
```

#### Target-Array

```php
[
    "A12312" => [
        "id"     => "A12312",
        "status" => false,
        "status" => true,
    ],
    "A12313" => [
        "id"     => "A12313",
        "status" => false,
        "status" => false,
    ],
    "A12314" => [
        "id"     => "A12314",
        "status" => true,
        "status" => false,
    ],
    "A12315" => [
        "id"     => "A12315",
        "status" => true,
        "status" => true,
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_column` to extract the `id` values into a flat array, and then use `array_combine` with that and the original array.

```
$input = [
    [
        "id"      => "A12312",
        "status"  => false,
        "enabled" => true,
    ],
    [
        "id"      => "A12313",
        "status"  => false,
        "enabled" => false,
    ],
    [
        "id"      => "A12314",
        "status"  => true,
        "enabled" => false,
    ],
    [
        "id"      => "A12315",
        "status"  => true,
        "enabled" => true,
    ],
];

$ids = array_column($input, 'id');

$result = array_combine($ids, $input);

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/VD1Fh